# Равномерное распределение трафика между сетевыми интерфейсов [bond] Centos 6.4

Tags: linux, сеть

трафик распределяется неравномерно по обеим сетевым картам.

Что может быть не так?

```
Iface               Total                IPv4               IPv6               NonIP              BadIP                       Activity
bond0                5913                5910                  3                   0                  0                31,80 kbits/sec                    x    x
eth0                 2212                2209                  3                   0                  0                 4,60 kbits/sec                    x    x
eth1                 3701                3701                  0                   0                  0                27,20 kbits/sec                    x    x
lo                    288                 288                  0                   0                  0                 0,00 kbits/sec                    x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить еще раз настройки [Bonding’a](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BondingInterfaces) Проверить настройки коммутатора.